# Eclipse Indigo Font Changed

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

So I just upgraded to Eclipse Indigo and it seems the Java text editor font has changed.

It seems to be Consolas. Does anyone know what the previous default editor font was so I can revert back?

Everyone here has moved to Indigo at the same time and no one knows what the default was in previous eclipse versions...

Comment: It might be one of Segoe UI, System, Fixedsys, Courier New,...

Comment: Why do people remove previous versions of eclipse? I usually keep them for a year or two... just to have a reference ;)

Comment: Because Help > Check for Updates is so easy, but you do make a good point.

Comment: I cannot comment yet, but here is why : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320616

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The font I think you are looking for is Courier New 10

Comment: Yup thats the one, thanks! The power of stack overflow, a helpful answer in less than 10 mins! Cheers guys!

Comment: There is lot of options in Color and Fonts, change Basic->Text Font to Courier New 10.

Answer (score 12):

It is Courier New 10.  For changing: **Windows/Preferences/General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts**